# Using Stripe Checkout with a form_for tag

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

In my application, users can create a booking. It is a simple model, with a form asking for their name. To create a booking, the user must pay. I am using the stripe checkout form for this. Right now, it has the "Pay with Card" button and this asks for their payment info. It takes this, and then redirects it to my booking confirmed page. However, the booking has been created, but the charge has not been done, as this is processed in `booking_charges_controller` whereas my booking is processed in its own controller.
 **How do I collect the card info, and only submit it once the booking form has been created, ddespite the fact that they are in different controllers?**

Could this be done by AJAX, or moving the logic into one controller?

Comment: I suggest you watch the following screencast http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe they are using one controller, but they are blocking save until the charge is done.

Comment: I have watched that screencast, but he is using a custom payment form. I am thinking about using their checkout script. Something similar to this https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails